# Getting Update Annotaion in Azure Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Azure Graph APIs to retrieve Information such as Mail, ProxyAddresses for User and Group.
Though there are @removed Annotations to indicate the Deleted users, 
Is there any Annotation to specifically indicate an Update done to a User.

Is there a way to get the Updates for a User or a User in a group.

The Below are the URL that i am trying to get information on :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta/?$select=id,mail,proxyaddresses

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?&$select=id,mailEnabled,mail,proxyAddresses,members

There is no way to identify an Update to the Mail or ProxyAddress for a Particular User in Groups or User.
Group members only inidicate the user id which doesnt specify its an Addition or an Update to the User.

Answer (score 0):

`/users/delta` can trace the update of Mail and ProxyAddresses of a user.

But `/groups/delta` can't trace the update of Mail and ProxyAddresses of a user in group. `/groups/delta` is only for getting incremental changes for groups, not for its members.

You can test `/users/delta` like this:

1. Call `GET
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta/?$select=id,mail,proxyaddresses`.
   There is a property "@odata.nextLink" in the response. Call the
   nextLink URL in Microsoft Graph Explorer for one or more times until
   there is "@odata.deltaLink" in the response.
2. Add or delete an alias in O365 admin center. Reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-user-s-email-alias-cb86b53b-bebf-4e0a-b781-c49270d85ea3).
3. Call the deltaLink URL to see there is a change of proxyAddresses in
   the response.

Comment: Is there a way or a API to get Incremental Changes for Users in a Group? I mean to say if members are changed within the Group, we do get the Delta in the form of:"members@delta": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            ] Although this doesnt clearly indicate if its an Addition or an Update to the Member in that group.

Comment: @user6230298 No. The API to get Incremental Changes in Microsoft Graph is /delta. As I mentioned above, it doesn't support to get changes for a group user using /group/delta.

Comment: @user6230298, if my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.